# Add programmatically TableRows and TextViews to XML file

Tags: android, mysql, xml, tableview, tablerow

I am trying to code my first Android application and I am stuck because I cannot display the data.
Basically I've a database to store some details about expenses (id, date, category, price and info/description), and I've no problems to insert the data.
Now I would like to have a page/activity to display all the database, so I thought to create an XML file with just the table, and then to add dinamically the rows I need to show all the results. I've found some code here on StackOverflow but it doesn't work, every time I open the activity I see nothing (but I'm sure that there are entries in the DB because I've another page that sums up the total amount of money spent by category and everything is ok).

I post the code:

**activity_display_database.xml**

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrl_database"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <TableLayout    android:id="@+id/database_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="5">
        <!-- header: i put buttons because in future they should order the results-->
        <TableRow
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <Button   android:id="@+id/database_id_tag"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/database_id_tag"
                android:onClick="displayAll"/>

            <Button   android:id="@+id/database_date_tag"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/database_date_tag" />

            <Button   android:id="@+id/database_category_tag"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/database_category_tag" />

            <Button   android:id="@+id/database_price_tag"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/database_price_tag" />

            <Button   android:id="@+id/database_info_tag"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/database_info_tag" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**DisplayDatabase.java**
*It receives in input the cursor of the results of the query and should put these results in rows in the table already created*

```
public void displayDatabase(Cursor crs){

    /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
    TableLayout database_table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.database_table);

    if (crs == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "cursor null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // for loop to scan the entries of the database
        for (crs.moveToFirst(); !crs.isAfterLast(); crs.moveToNext()) {
            TableRow database_row = new TableRow(ctx);
            for (int column_number = 0; column_number < COLUMNS_NUMBER; column_number++){
                TextView a_slot = new TextView(this);
                a_slot.setText(crs.getString(column_number));
                database_row.addView(a_slot);
            }
            database_table.addView(database_row);
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: did you checked whether cursor is null?

Comment: I checked. It isn't!

Comment: I changed the code, now I think it's more correct, but still it doesn't work!